# Create a dynamic onClick() which implements View.OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, imageview, onclicklistener

currently my code is quite a bit of redundant code as below:

```
iv_11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
            doStuff(iv_11, theCard);
        }
    });

    iv_12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
            doStuff(iv_12, theCard);
        }
    });

    iv_13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
            doStuff(iv_13, theCard);
        }
    });

    iv_14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
            doStuff(iv_14, theCard);
        }
    });
```

so, I have decided to implements View.OnClickListener to make it same thing dynamic and so in my class, i implements View.OnClickListener and then i replace the above code with below:

```
    iv_11.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv_12.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv_13.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv_14.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and finally, I add this below code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
    doStuff(?, theCard);
}
```

Problem is what should I put in the question mark above?

Comment: What is `doStuff()` here may be **`doStuff(v, theCard);`**

Comment: After putting 'v', i got this error: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.view.View', required: 'android.widget.ImageView'

Comment: Share your your `doStuff()` method with question

Comment: private void doStuff(ImageView iv, int card) { ... }

Comment: @Steve can u share your whole `doStuff()` method in question

Comment: after i did this ok already. not sure if it is good though.     public void onClick(View v) {
        int theCard = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
        doStuff((ImageView)v, theCard);
    }

Comment: @Steve try v.getId()

Comment: Vishva Dave, v.getId() doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

doStuff method should be invoked as following code.

```
doStuff((ImageView)v, theCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the view argument as

```
doStuff(v, theCard);
```